# How to use macro arguments in call to another macro?

Tags: c++, macros

I'd like to be able to create a macro which calls other macros. The macro I'd like to call is the `Benchmark` macro from [folly](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/Benchmark.md).

Ultimately, I'd like to have a bunch of macros that look like:

```
BENCHMARK(filter_10_vector_1_filter, n) { ... }
BENCHMARK(filter_10_set_1_filter, n) { ... }
BENCHMARK(filter_10_vector_2_filter, n) { ... }
BENCHMARK(filter_10_set_2_filter, n) { ... }
BENCHMARK(filter_10_vector_3_filter, n) { ... }
BENCHMARK(filter_10_set_3_filter, n) { ... }
... all the way to 10_filter

BENCHMARK(filter_100_vector_1_filter, n) { ... }
BENCHMARK(filter_100_set_1_filter, n) { ... }
... all the way to 10_filter
```

I tried creating a macro that looks like:

```
#define CreateBenchmark(numElements, numFilters) \
  BENCHMARK(filter_##numElements_vector_##numFilters_filters, n) { ... } \
  BENCHMARK_RELATIVE(filter_##numElements_set_##numFilters_filters, n) { ... }

CreateBenchmark(10, 2);
```

which would hopefully halve the number of macros I need to write. However, the `##numElements` and `##numFilters` substitutions are not happening as I hoped. The result of the `CreateBenchmark(10, 2)` call is

```
============================================================================
FilterWithSetBenchmark.cpp  relative  time/iter  iters/s
============================================================================
filter_numElements_vector_numFilters_filters               264.35us    3.78K
filter_numElements_set_numFilters_filters         99.93%   264.54us    3.78K
============================================================================
```

I was expecting `filter_10_vector_2_filters` and `fitler_10_set_2_filters`. Is there a way to sub the values supplied to the `CreateBenchmark` macro into the values passed to the `BENCHMARK` and `BENCHMARK_RELATIVE` calls?

As a bonus, can my `CreateBenchmark` macro use a for loop to create all of the `XX_filters` so that one call to `CreateBenchmark` generates 20 macro calls (10 for `_vector_` and 10 for `_set_`)?

Comment: Thanks for showing what may be the first reasonable use of `##` I have ever seen. Do you use trigraphs by any chance?

Comment: No problem, I guess? :p What situations do you normally see `##` used in? No, I don't use trigraphs, just writing some regular benchmark-using-a-set-instead code.

Comment: I don't think I've seen `##` outside totally contrived examples. That's how I thought of trigraphs.

Comment: Interesting. This is my first time writing a c++ macro but while I was learning I glanced at some libraries we depend on (forget which ones) and saw a few examples there.

Comment: I don't do much with C++, but I would expect it would crop up there more than in pure C just from sheer volume. If I remember, things like boost and gtest are pretty macro-intensive, increasing the chance that something like `##` would crop up in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the trailing concatenation operator `##`:

```
#define CreateBenchmark(numElements, numFilters) \
  BENCHMARK(filter_ ## numElements ## _vector_ ## numFilters ## _filters, n) { ... } \
  BENCHMARK_RELATIVE(filter_ ## numElements ## _set_ ## numFilters ## _filters, n) { ... }
```

Think of `##` as the string concatenation operator just like `+` in Java or Python.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out by accident. My create macro function needed more `#`. Here's the new one:

```
#define CreateBenchmark(numElements, numFilters) \
  BENCHMARK(filter_##numElements##_vector_##numFilters##_filters, n) { ... } \
  BENCHMARK_RELATIVE(filter_##numElements##_set_##numFilters##_filters, n) { ... }
```

Basically, what I want subbed needs to be completely enclosed in double `#`. Went from `##numElements` to `##numElements##`. Similarly for `numFilters`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `__VA_ARGS__` to represent the macro arguments.

Comment: How would that be even remotely applicable to the OP's situation?